# @click event not triggering alongside element with @blur

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, onclick, blur

I've got a problem when working with VueJS which is kinda getting on my nerfs since I know that it probably relies on something very small but still I'm here trying to get it running for hours.

I'm using a template which should represent a searchbar with the solutions under it. To show the solutions, I'm looping over an object (I'm not done including the filtering of the solutions to that point - wanted to finish this one first). The thing I was trying to do now was filling in the searchbar value with the value I select in the solutions (passing it with a click event). But somehow my click event doesn't trigger.

I've got the following code-snippet:

```
<template>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="input-group-text">&#128269;</div>
        </div>
        <input 
            type="text" 
            class="form-control"
            @focus="searchFocus = true"
            @blur="searchFocus = false"
            v-model="searchQuery"
            placeholder="Search for vehicles..">
        <div class="container p-0">
            <div class="dropdown-menu search" v-show="searchFocus">
                <a class="dropdown-item bus" href="#" 
                    v-for="vehicle in vehicleObjects" 
                    :key="vehicle.id.key"
                    v-on:click="setSelectedToQuery(vehicle)">
                    <span class="ml-4">Bus {{ vehicle.id.name }}
                        <span class="badge badge-secondary"> {{ vehicle.licenseNumber }}</span>
                    <span>
                </a>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Am I missing something quite obvious? How can I get the click-event running/triggering?

Thanks in advance

Best Regards

Comment: It looks fine to me.  Did you breakpoint setSelectedToQuery to make sure it actually isn't entering the function?  There are no errors on the console right?

Comment: Does a click event works in inner spans in 'a' tag?

Comment: Also, are you using `.stop` to prevent bubbling or preventing default anywhere above the component?

Comment: @user120242 yeah I'm trying to catch it with alerts & console.logs but yeah.. nothing and no, I'm not using `.stop`

Comment: @Anatoly nope, same result => nothing.. :/

Comment: Maybe check the element inspector to see if you have any elements covering it?  Did you try placing an alert or console.log directly into the v-on:click?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are few things "off" I'll list them by level of impact

- `@blur` fires before click, essentially invalidating `@click`
- anchors `<a ...>` need to prevent redirect. You can use `@click.prevent="...` to prevent event propagation, or use another element, since you don't have `href` defined anyway.
- one of your `span` elements is not closed (`<span>` instead of `</span` at the end)

To handle `@blur` blocking `@click`, you could use `@mousedown` instead of `@click`, since it executes first.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Using `@mousedown` worked perfectly fine!
The span thing is kinda funny tho.. how could I not realize that

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's the solution: close your last span

Click work for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-browser-fgftf

Comment: Seems that the span didn't cause the issue, but anyways thanks for that hint! :)